# Testing a jsonify response - python

Tags: unit-testing, flask

I have the following method in Flask that return a `jsonify` response, so when hitting `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status` route, it should renderize in a browser

```
[
     {
       user: "admin"
     },
     { 
       result: "OK - Healthy"
     }
]
```

The method is this:

```
@app.route('/status')
def health_check():
    response = [
        {'user': 'admin'},
        {'result': 'OK - Healthy'}
    ]
    
    return jsonify(response)
```

I am trying to build a test case that examine the content of the `jsonify(response)` object returned:

```
class HealthStatusCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_health_check(self):
        response = health_check()
        self.assertEqual(response, ['200 OK'])
```

But I don't know how to check the content of a `jsonify` output, the above test is misleading.
When I check the value of the `jsonify(response)` I get

```
pdb> jsonify(response)
<Response 71 bytes [200 OK]>
ipdb>
```

But that I am interested in is to access to the content of the `response` list, such as:

`{'result': 'OK - Healthy'}` and compare that key value pair.

**UPDATE**

I've followed the pytest approach suggested, by working with a fixture to make a request to `/status` endpoint, so the test case is now like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_health_check(client):
    response = client.get('/status')
    assert response.json == [
        {'user': 'admin'},
        {'result': 'OK - Healthy'}
    ]
```

When I execute `python -m pytest tests/test_health_check.py` the test pass:

```
> python -m pytest tests/test_health_check.py  
============================================================== test session starts ===============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/../../
plugins: flask-1.2.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                 

tests/test_health_check.py .                                                                                                               [100%]

=============================================================== 1 passed in 0.11s ================================================================
```

But then something that I miss is that if I modified the `assert response.json` content to let's say like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_health_check(client):
    response = client.get('/status')
    assert response.json == [
        {'user': 'admin'},
        {'result': 'OKdsdsd - Healthy'}
    ]
```

The test also pass
I know a feature is intended to ilustrate a behavior and run it inside a test, but is there a way to make a relationship with the original values of the json in my orginal `response` list? I feel that this test is non meaningful.

Comment: You can remove `@pytest.fixture` from `def test_health_check` in your update. It will work anyway

Comment: I don't fully understand, what you want to test? Can you decribe by words for example, what scenario you want to test

Comment: I want to test the JSON response (from the response list that I apply jsonify)  from the health_check method above. Either a key value or the entire response which I got it when hitting the `/status` endpoint when running a flask app.

By the way If I remove `@pytest.fixture` I got this error https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/d1a4ea20cd78a82f07711d88b24761f9

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say that you should add some fixtures to your `tests/conftest.py` file. `test_health_check` is not a fixture, ыo it should be no fixture decorator wrapping it. See my update to an answer

Comment: What means "test the JSON response" in your case? I thought that it means that you want to check if `/status` endpoint return certain value

Answer (score 2):

Better use `pytest` library for testing.
With it your code will be super simple

```py
def test_health_check(client):
    response = client.get('/status')
    assert response.json ==  [
        {'user': 'admin'},
        {'result': 'OK - Healthy'}
    ]
```

Based on Flask docs article about testing: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/

Docs for pytest: https://docs.pytest.org/

**Update:**

In order to make the test above to work you should add this to `tests/conftest.py`

```py
import pytest
from my_project import create_app

@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.update({
        "TESTING": True,
    })

    yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

Or if you not have smth as a `create_app` function

```py
import pytest
from my_project import app

@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

Copied from: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/#fixtures

Comment: can you check my UPDATE please?